# HPCC Platform and Ganglia / Nagios plugin

Tags: hpcc-ecl

With most users moving toward cloud-based deployments, will the Nagios / Ganglia plugin continue to be supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 8.12.x, support for our Nagios/Ganglia Reporting and Monitoring plugin will be deprecated. The plugin will no longer be built or distributed. The installer packages for older versions of the plugin will continue to be available on our archive page.

Standalone system monitoring via Ganglia/Nagios is not affected by this change. You can also choose to use other options, such as Prometheus, Grafana, or cloud-provided services.